# Trying to make custom recipe in tModLoader

Tags: c#

I am following a tutorial on YouTube to create a simple sword with a custom recipe in tModLoader 1.4. (I am using cheatsheat to give myself the items, and I want to be able to craft my sword with an anvil and 8 tutorial items).
The link to the tutorial is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HS3OV6xuNI&ab_channel=Lynx if you need.

The item code:

```
using Terraria.ModLoader;
using Terraria.ID;
using Terraria.GameContent.Creative;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

namespace OverpoweredStuff.Content.Items
{
    internal class TutorialItem : ModItem
    {
        public override void SetStaticDefaults()
        {
            DisplayName.SetDefault("Tutorial Item");
            Tooltip.SetDefault("pog");
            CreativeItemSacrificesCatalog.Instance.SacrificeCountNeededByItemId[Type] = 100;
        }

        public override void SetDefaults()
        {
            Item.width = 16;
            Item.height = 16;

            Item.value = Item.buyPrice(copper: 5);
            Item.maxStack = 999;
        }
    }
}
```

The code for the sword:

```
using Terraria;
using Terraria.ModLoader;
using Terraria.ID;
using Terraria.GameContent.Creative;

namespace TutorialMod.Content.Items.Weapons
{
    internal class TutorialSword : ModItem
    {
        public override void SetStaticDefaults()
        {
            DisplayName.SetDefault("Tutorial Sword");
            Tooltip.SetDefault("This is a modded Broadsword");
            CreativeItemSacrificesCatalog.Instance.SacrificeCountNeededByItemId[Type] = 1;
        }

        public override void SetDefaults()
        {
            Item.width = 32;
            Item.height = 32;

            Item.useStyle = ItemUseStyleID.Swing;
            Item.useTime  = 20;
            Item.useAnimation = 20;
            Item.autoReuse = true;

            Item.DamageType = DamageClass.Melee;
            Item.damage = 69;
            Item.knockBack = 3.5f;
            Item.crit = 5;

            Item.value = Item.buyPrice(silver: 80, copper: 50);
            Item.rare = ItemRarityID.Blue;

            Item.UseSound = SoundID.Item1;
        }

        public override void AddRecipes()
        {
            CreateRecipe()
                .AddIngredients(ModContent.ItemType<TutorialItem>(), 8)
                .AddTile(TileID.Anvils)
                .Register();
        }
    } 
}
```

The error:
[image]
My files are structured like this:
[image]

EDIT:
I noticed an error on the first line of create recipe with < instead of >, and now get this error:
[image]

When trying with a vanilla material `.AddIngredient(2, 8)` I get the original error.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It can't be copied or pasted.

Answer (score 0):

It may be different because I'm using a different software, however try removing "(ModContent.ItemType" & ", 8)" then put the 8 into the parenthesis that remain so your code will look like: .AddIngredient(8)
As long as this item is in the same folder as the sword it should work

I would reccomend changing your "content/item" folder name to one word stuff like "Items" or compoud stuff like "ContentItems" and adjust namespaces and such to match so you can pull ingredients from other folders

Try this and let me know if it works please: .AddIngredient<(New folder name no parenthesis).TutorialItem>(8)
which might look like: .AddIngredient<ContentItems.TutorialItem>(8)